# Как правильно использовать jQuery load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подгружаю данные, но не хочу создавать много отдельных файлов с текстами. Можно ли к примеру в одном файле как то разметить данные и подгружать по выбору?

```
$(".comm").click(function(){
    $("#div").load("/load.php");
});
```

Comment: Наверное можно. Но из вопроса не совсем ясно в чем проблема. А так можно посоветовать и базу данных и просто хранение в одном большом текстовом файле.

Comment: @newman можно пример с текстовым файлом?

Comment: я не привержинец таких решений. Я, если бы меня приперло бы, то реализовывал в отдельных файлах. Отдельные файлы и проще редактировать и если что-то пойдет не так, то потеряешь один файл, а не все данные сразу. Ну а с одним файлом примера у меня нет. Есть идея - придумать некий разделитель. Например ==num== - где num - это номер блока. Этот номер блока передавать в load.php как параметр. На его основе находить в файле кусок между этим и следующим разделителем и выводить его. Реализация не сложная. Вот поддерживать и актуализировать потом это сложно.

Comment: у меня такая же идея была, но реализовать я такое быстро не смогу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) позволяет выбрать какой фрагмент из загруженного документа нужно вставить.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

При выполнении этого метода будет получено содержимое `ajax/test.html`, но затем в нем будет выбран элемент с `id=container`. Этот элемент вместе со своим содержимым будет вставлен в элемент с `id=result`, а все остальное содержимое `ajax/test.html` будет отброшено.

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо

Comment: Насколько эффективно использовать load? Стоит или нет?

Comment: @spoon100500, эффективно по сравнению с чем?

Comment: @Grungy ,по сравнению с ajax или get ?

Comment: @spoon100500 `load`, это обертка над `ajax`, `get` - это обертка над `ajax`, их разница только в том, что в load можно выбрать конкретный элемент из загруженного Html, А get сразу возвращает все.